# Drag & Drop Image Position Issue On Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am placing an image on the canvas using drap & drop but the problem is, after dropping the image on canvas, image is loosing it's original position where it is dropped.

Sometimes it comes down from the original position and sometimes moves to right. Here is the code:

```
 $("#draggable1").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
       var canv = document.getElementById("tools_sketch");
       var rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();
       x = event.clientX - rect.left;
       y = event.clientY - rect.top;

       ans = confirm("Is it correct position?");
       if (ans)
       {

          dropimg_over_ground("img1", x, y);
          $('#draggable1').remove();

       }

    }

 });
 dropimg_over_ground = function(imgid, lefti, topi)
 {
    var c = document.getElementById("tools_sketch");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById(imgid);
    ctx.drawImage(img, lefti, topi);
 }
```

I have searched forum alot and tried many solutions but it's not worked.

Comment: What procedure do you have in place if the image is larger than the drop area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just subtract the offset of the container:

```
$('#drag').draggable({
    stop: function(e, ui){
        console.log('drag');

        console.log($(this).offset().top - $('#canvas').offset().top)
        console.log($(this).offset().left - $('#canvas').offset().left)
    }
});

$("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: "#drag",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('dragged out');
    }
});
```

Working example,
http://jsfiddle.net/kBM6u/6/

check the console for the results

Regards

Comment: Thanks Jorge for your answer but unfortunately it's not working. When I use x = event.offsetX;y = event.offsetY; it does not show up image on canvas. Any other solution?

Comment: Am I missing something??

Comment: Thanks alot Jorge. It's working like a charm. Before that, I tried many solution but nothing worked...